# Order a Django queryset by another dict

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

So, right now I have this model and a calculated dictionary

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)


#scores dict {user_id: score}
scores = {1: 9, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 5}
```

I need to order the queryset based on each user score in the scores dict. Something like this

Views.py

```
queryset.annotate(score=scores['user_id']).order_by('score')
```

Comment: How are the scores calculated? If it's the result of another query you may be able to do it without the dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but this is rather "strange":

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value, When

queryset.annotate(
    score=Case(
        *[When(user_id=k, then=Value(v)) for k,v in scores.items()]
        default=None,
        output_field=IntegerField(null=True)
    )
).order_by('score')
```

It is probably better to just store the scores in the related `User` model (to which the `user_id` is referring).